# grunt-notify: Doesn't trigger on success

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-notify

I am attempting to setup [grunt-notify](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify) with [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) and [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).  Generally this is working well but I can't get grunt-notify to notify me when grunt-less is executed successfully.

If anyone has any insight on how to set this up or debug, happy to have any input.

---

Full info:

I have setup grunt-notify to trigger whenever less has run using a watch.  This works great when the less task fails.  Gives me a great pop-up error:

[image]

For reference this is the console output:

[image]

**When less succeeds, I am not getting any notification.  I would like to get a notification but cannot figure out how to enable this.**

This is the console output when less succeeds:

[image]

This is the GruntFile that I am using:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: true
                },
                files: {
                    "FILE.css": "FILE2.less"
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            less: {
                files: '**/*.less',
                tasks: ['less', 'notify_hooks']
            }
        },


        notify_hooks: {
            options: {
                message: "MESSAGE"
            }

        }


    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');

    grunt.registerTask("default", ['less']);

};
```

---

[Original question on Github](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify/issues/84)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a message for your task to the gruntfile and specify which task it is going to give that message for. See below

```
notify: {
    less:{
        options:{
            title: "CSS Files built",
            message: "Less task complete"
        }
    }
}
```

For reference you can see them use in the [git repo readme](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify#showing-specific-notifications)

Added for completeness:

As uKolka has mentioned below, you will also require the watch task to be updated as per his solution:

```
watch: {
    less: {
        files: '**/*.less',
        tasks: ['less', 'notify:less']
    }
},
```

Where `notify:less` references the less task within the notifiy object.

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I tried this yesterday, but it didnt work.  Works now though, so thanks! - Will accept this as the accepted answer in 5 minutes (once allowed).

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that specifying the notification task...

```
notify: {
    less:{
        options:{
            title: "CSS Files built"
            message: "Less task complete"
        }
    }
}
```

... is just a part of the deal.

It also should be registered in a task that you want it to be triggered for.

So for original OP's code to work

```
    watch: {
        less: {
            files: '**/*.less',
            tasks: ['less', 'notify_hooks']
        }
    },
```

should be changed to

```
    watch: {
        less: {
            files: '**/*.less',
            tasks: ['less', 'notify:less']
        }
    },
```

This references the `notify:less` mentioned earlier.

Comment: This answer has the true solution to where most people may falter in configuring things right.